# mysql and java (observing updates, creating tables, removing tables and editing information)

Tags: java, mysql, observer-pattern

I am working on an application for java right now that will be using a remote mySQL database running on a linux machine. I am wanting to be able to observe the data (basically have an observer attached to one of the tables to let my application know when something has changed). I am wanting to be able to create tables, view tables and edit tables.

**I was wondering what my options were in java for this type of need.** Please let me know of any issues you ran into while trying to achieve this type of functionality.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest answer i could find to what i wanted is JDBC.